# changing the color of an SVG circle using a button in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

so i wanted to make a circle in HTML using SVGs and changing its color from blue to red but i had problems while trying to make a function for changing the color. this is my script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .button {
          background-color: rgb(209, 16, 16);
          border: none;
          color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
          padding: 15px 32px;
          text-align: center;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: inline-block;
          font-size: 20px;
          margin: 4px 2px;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>



</head>
<body>
        <script  >
            function change() { getElementById('dayereh').css.color= 'red'} 

        </script>
    <svg id="dayereh" width="1370" height="1070">
        <circle cx="500" cy="500" r="400" stroke="black" stroke-width="30" fill="blue" />

     </svg> 
<button  class="button" id="btn-test1" onclick="change()">change color</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What problem are you running into? Remember to share any error messages you encounter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be like this. Also The `id` must be in the `circle`.

```js
function change() { 
  document.getElementById('dayereh').style.fill = "red";
}
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: rgb(209, 16, 16);
  border: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg  width="1370" height="1070">
  <circle id="dayereh" cx="500" cy="500" r="400" stroke="black" stroke-width="30" fill="blue" />
</svg> 
<button  class="button" id="btn-test1" onclick="change()">change color</button>
```

Comment: @DogukanCavas sorry i don't know how im new to this site

Comment: @AliAgharazi Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <style>
     .button {
       background-color: rgb(209, 16, 16);
       border: none;
       color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
       padding: 15px 32px;
       text-align: center;
       text-decoration: none;
       display: inline-block;
       font-size: 20px;
       margin: 4px 2px;
       cursor: pointer;
     }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
 <script>
  function change() {
    document.querySelector('#dayereh circle').setAttribute("fill","0000FF");
  } 
 </script>
 <svg id="dayereh" width="1370" height="1070">
   <circle cx="500" cy="500" r="400" stroke="black" stroke-width="30" fill="blue" />
 </svg> 
 <button  class="button" id="btn-test1" onclick="change()">change color</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but i didnt want to use query .(it worked BTW)